# Are there languages with discontinued subordinate clauses?

Tags: cross-linguistic, sentences, subordination, complex-sentences

As for the languages I know I think to believe, that a subordinated clause comes in a chunk and not scattered throughout the main clause.

For instance:

> I LIKE TO SING, while i slave away

*while I slave away* is the subordinated clause and in one continuous piece, there is nothing like:

> - I  while LIKE i TO slave SING away

Now I don't know if this contradicts some basic principle in linguistics, but a friend of mine,Aslan, who admittingly tends to be a crackpot, but has also proven to be smart, claims, that this is the case in one of the Balkan languages he speaks.

The example I provide is necessarily just wrong grammar I had to make up, to exemplify what I mean.

Comment: Can you ask him to provide glossed examples? If so, you can just ask another speaker of that language whether the examples and glosses are correct...

Comment: "I saw [a rabbit that hopped away] yesterday" ==> "I saw [a rabbit] yesterday [that hopped away]."

Answer (score 1):

This sort of behavior certainly occurs in some languages. Here's an example from Meskwaki where a relative clause is interspersed with the matrix clause:

> **iiniyeeka** [peeminehkawaatshiki **ashaahaki** ihkweewani]
>
> those.abs     chase 3p-3'/part.3p Sioux.pl  woman.obv
>
> those who they chased her the Sioux the woman
>
> "Those Sioux who were chasing the woman"

The head of the relative clause is the noun *Sioux*, but it appears internal to the relative clause.

Comment: Again, I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. The subordinate clause is still in one piece in the sentence...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how this would be viewed in English but you can find a certain discontinuity in European languages:

*I don't know **what** you think you are doing.*

*Nevím, **co** si myslíš, že děláš.*

In Czech, word *dělat* (*to do*) comes with obligatory transitivity (unless in it means *to work (in order to earn money)*) and thus requires a direct object. In this sentence, the direct object would be *co* (*what*) but this is moved at the beginning of the first-order subordinate and merged with its own relative pronoun.

Comment: Parentheticals can break up subordinate clauses.  E.g., "I like to sing as i slave (which rhymes with "wave") away."

Comment: I'm not sure the English example is what the OP is looking for. The 'what' is still within the subordinate clause, despite the long-distance dependency. The OP seems to be looking for examples where the subordinate clause is 'interlaced' in the main clause.